# FadeOut div on page load

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using this code to fadeout a div once my page has loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT LOADING DIV
   $('#Loading').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Its working fine, however i have a page where i load other pages using JQuery:

```
$('.EditCustomer').load("editcustomer_company.php");
```

The div `#Loading` and the fade out function is in a file called settings.php which is included (`<?php include 'settings.php';`) which is on every page (including `editcustomer_company.php`)

when i visit the page that loads `editcustomer_company.php` the `#Loading` div appears however does not fade out

Comment: the JS code is being included from the php included file because its showing the code in the source and its showing the loading div but its just not disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `load` does not perform a load on the window object.  However, there is 'complete' call back that can be used.

```
$('.EditCustomer').load("editcustomer_company.php", function() {
    $('#Loading').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/